# PostgreSQL error updating ResultSet "No primary key found for table" on table w/key

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to do an update on a ResultSet and I'm getting an exception, `No primary key found for table nvp,` on a table that has a primary key.

It's PostgreSQL 9.6.1.0, and jdbc driver version is postgresql-9.4.1212.jar downloaded from their website (JDBC42 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.4.1212 from [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)).

```
@Test
public void testUpdateableResultSet() throws Exception {
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dot";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "dot_test");
    props.setProperty("password", "test_dot");
    props.setProperty("currentSchema", "dot_test");

    try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props)) {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        try(Statement s = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)) {
            s.execute("drop table if exists nvp");
            s.execute("create table nvp (id int primary key, value text);");
            s.execute("insert into nvp (id, value) values (1, 'one_'), (2, 'two_')");
        }

        try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select value from nvp", 
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while(rs.next()) {
                String s = rs.getString(1);
                if(s.endsWith("_")) {
                    s = s.replace("_", "");
                }
                else {
                    s = s + "_";
                }
                rs.updateString(1, s);              // line 28
                System.out.println("row updated");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the following result.

```
Testcase: testUpdateableResultSet(com.tekbot.lib.sql.SimpleTest):   Caused an ERROR
No primary key found for table nvp.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No primary key found for table nvp.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.isUpdateable(PgResultSet.java:1586)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.checkUpdateable(PgResultSet.java:2722)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.updateValue(PgResultSet.java:3056)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.updateString(PgResultSet.java:1393)
    at com.tekbot.lib.sql.SimpleTest.testUpdateableResultSet(SimpleTest.java:28)
```

Is this a bug? Am I missing a step?

Comment: which line is line 28?

Comment: @ScaryWombat `rs.updateString(1, s);`

Comment: Does this happen on the first iteration of the `while`?  Are you missing an `updateRow()` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat It happens on the first pass through the loop. I'll add an `updateRow()` but I don't think it will make a difference.

Comment: as @ScaryWombat pointed out you should add `updateRow()`. Maybe you could try select the id on the statement: `select id, value from nvp`

Comment: No difference in the result (edit: that was for adding the updateRow)

Comment: I changed the query to `select value, id from nvp` and now is good. Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The primary key must be specified so that the result set is updateable

Change your query on `line 17` to:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select id, value from nvp"...
```

Comment: Where is that quote from?

Comment: pretty obvious in hindsight eh

Comment: I dont know how to add an e-book reference, but it is from: JDBC Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach, Chapter 6, Section 9 "How Do You Create an Updatable ResultSet?"